# Simple algorithm for annotations request from server on map

Tags: ios, algorithm, dictionary, route-me

What is a good enough method of knowing when to go out to the server and request for annotations?
i.e. knowing when the area on the screen was not yet exposed by the user?

If I have a `LAT1,LON1` `LAT2,LON2` specifying the screen boundaries, or maybe the screen's center as `LAT,LON`, how can I know that the surface the user has moved to has never been exposed or even just a part of it?

Weird, but I can't find ideas online, Any methods would be welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

store a set of `MKMapRect` objects that the map showed in a `NSMutableSet` maybe -- you then have all the areas that were visible previously. (combine rects when it makes sense to keep the set reasonable)

when you get a new `MKMapRect` (after a scroll or zoom of the map view -- the delegate is informed here) see if the new `visibleMapRect` lies within an old one or just intersects or is not inside the rect at all

an `MKMapRect` can be treated almost like a `CGRect` :)

Comment: The problem would remain, how to tell from the NSSet, if the new CGRect is inside the total of the set?

Comment: There is mkmaprect containsrect, intersects - as well as containspoint and MKMapPointFromCoordinate

Comment: Thats what i meant with equivalent to cgrect.